# How do you successfully change execution policy and enable execution of PowerShell scripts

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a problem regarding changing the *Execution Policy* in my Windows Server 2008+ OS. It is the first time I try to run a script for which I need resource full access and I try the following after starting *Powershell* in *elevated mode*:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

But I get this:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy : Windows PowerShell updated your execution policy
successfully, but the setting is overridden by a policy defined at a more
specific scope.  Due to the override, your shell will retain its current
effective execution policy of RemoteSigned. Type "Get-ExecutionPolicy -List"
to view your execution policy settings. For more information please see
"Get-Help Set-ExecutionPolicy".
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (:) [Set-ExecutionPolicy], SecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExecutionPolicyOverride,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetExecutionPolicyCommand
```

Though I am Administrator, I cannot change the Execution Policy. What to do?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The error message indicates that the setting you're trying to define via `Set-ExecutionPolicy` is overridden by a setting in another scope. Use `Get-ExecutionPolicy -List` to see which scope has which setting.

```
PS C:\> Get-ExecutionPolicy -List

        Scope    ExecutionPolicy
        -----    ---------------
MachinePolicy          Undefined
   UserPolicy          Undefined
      Process          Undefined
  CurrentUser          Undefined
 LocalMachine       RemoteSigned

PS C:\> Set-ExecutionPolicy Restricted -Scope Process -Force
PS C:\> Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser -Force
Set-ExecutionPolicy : Windows PowerShell updated your execution policy
successfully, but the setting is overridden by a policy defined at a more
specific scope.  Due to the override, your shell will retain its current
effective execution policy of Restricted. Type "Get-ExecutionPolicy -List"
to view your execution policy settings. ...
PS C:\> Get-ExecutionPolicy -List

        Scope    ExecutionPolicy
        -----    ---------------
MachinePolicy          Undefined
   UserPolicy          Undefined
      Process         Restricted
  CurrentUser       Unrestricted
 LocalMachine       RemoteSigned

PS C:\> .\test.ps1
.\test.ps1 : File C:\test.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is
disabled on this system. ...
PS C:\> Set-ExecutionPolicy Unestricted -Scope Process -Force
PS C:\> Set-ExecutionPolicy Restricted -Scope CurrentUser -Force
Set-ExecutionPolicy : Windows PowerShell updated your execution policy
successfully, but the setting is overridden by a policy defined at a more
specific scope.  Due to the override, your shell will retain its current
effective execution policy of Restricted. Type "Get-ExecutionPolicy -List"
to view your execution policy settings. ...
PS C:\> Get-ExecutionPolicy -List

        Scope    ExecutionPolicy
        -----    ---------------
MachinePolicy          Undefined
   UserPolicy          Undefined
      Process       Unrestricted
  CurrentUser         Restricted
 LocalMachine       RemoteSigned

PS C:\> .\test.ps1
Hello World!
```

As you can see, both settings were defined despite the error, but the setting in the more specific scope (`Process`) still takes precedence, either preventing or allowing script execution.

Since the default scope is `LocalMachine` the error could be caused by a setting in the `CurrentUser` or `Process` scope. However, a more common reason is that script execution was configured via a group policy (either local or domain).

A local group policy can be modified by a local administrator via `gpedit.msc` (Local Group Policy Editor) as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27753927/1630171).

A domain group policy cannot be superseded by local settings/policies and must be changed by a domain admin via `gpmc.msc` (Group Policy Management) on a domain controller.

For both local and domain policies the setting can be defined as a computer setting:

```
Computer Configuration
`-Administrative Templates
  `-Windows Components
    `-Windows PowerShell -> Turn on Script Execution
```

or as a user setting:

```
User Configuration
`-Administrative Templates
  `-Windows Components
    `-Windows PowerShell -> Turn on Script Execution
```

The former are applied to computer objects, whereas the latter are applied to user objects. For local polices there is no significant difference between user and computer policies, because user policies are automatically applied to all users on the computer.

A policy can have one of three states (or five states if you count the 3 settings available for the state *Enabled* separately):

- *Not Configured*: policy does not control PowerShell script execution.
- *Enabled*: allow PowerShell script execution.

  - *Allow only signed scripts*: allow execution of signed scripts only (same as `Set-ExecutionPolicy AllSigned`).
  - *Allow local scripts and remote signed scripts*: allow execution of all local scripts (signed or not) and of signed scripts from remote locations (same as `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned`).
  - *Allow all scripts*: allow execution of local and remote scripts regardless of whether they're signed or not (same as `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted`).
- *Disabled*: disallow PowerShell script execution (same as `Set-ExecutionPolicy Restricted`).

Changes made via `Set-ExecutionPolicy` only become effective when local and domain policies are set to *Not Configured* (execution policy `Undefined` in the scopes `MachinePolicy` and `UserPolicy`).

Answer (score 56):

The problem is that Windows does not allow all scripts to be executed in `Unrestricted` mode. Actually, no matter the execution policy for your user (even if administrator), the `Local Group Policy` will take priority.

And by default the local group script execution policy is such for which scripts are not allowed to be executed. We need to change it!

### Changing the Local Group Execution Policy

We do this via the `Local Group Policy Editor` which you can reach by searching in the Windows Search bar for "group policy". Or do this:

1. Open the Management Console by hitting `Win + r` and typing command `mmc`.
2. Go to `File -> Add Remove Snap In...`.
3. In the left pane find `Group Policy Object Editor` and add it.
4. Close the form.

Then on the left pane the group editor can be expanded. Expand it and navigate to `Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components`.

[image]

Then to `Windows PowerShell`.

[image]

So select `Turn on Script Execution`. Change configuration to `Enabled` and specify `Allow all scripts` in `Execution Policy`.

[image]

Confirm by hitting `Ok` and close the Management Console.

Comment: What do you do if Windows Power Shell is not in the list?

Comment: I found the answer, you need to download version 4 on Windows Power Shell from here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=40855

Comment: Additionally, I had to install the hotfix in the answer below by @diganta-kumar

Comment: I had to run also 
Set-ExecutionPolicy "Unrestricted" -Scope CurrentUser -Confirm:$false

Comment: @RobSedgwick i think ur window home yes, so dont try open gpedit.msc e first use mmc with console prompt+admin.

Answer (score 11):

A hotfix is now available to install:

2.8.7 for VS 2013:
https://github.com/NuGet/Home/releases/download/2.8.7/NuGet.Tools.vsix

3.1.1 for VS 2015:
https://github.com/NuGet/Home/releases/download/3.1.1/NuGet.Tools.vsix

https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/974

Comment: Beware that this answer is unrelated to the problem described in the question. It resolves a problem with a Visual Studio extension.

Answer (score 8):

If the PowerShell ExecutionPolicy is being set by a Domain Controller through a group policy, you'll have to reset the ExecutionPolicy to "Bypass" in the registry after every boot.  I've created a pair of startup scripts to automate the process. Below, I describe my process.

Create a folder called %USERPROFILE%\Documents\StartupScripts and then place a PowerShell script called ExecutionPolicy.ps1 in it with following code:

```
Push-Location
Set-Location HKLM:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell
Set-ItemProperty . ExecutionPolicy "Bypass"
Pop-Location
```

Then create a file called %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\Startup.cmd and place the following code in it:

```
PowerShell -Version 3.0 -Command "Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted" >> "%TEMP%\StartupLog.txt" 2>&1
PowerShell -Version 3.0 "%USERPROFILE%\Documents\StartupScripts\ExecutionPolicy.ps1" >> "%TEMP%\StartupLog.txt" 2>&1
```

This script will run at the start of every login.

Comment: I don't think this gets around the group policy. At least not for me. In my case the key did not exist under HKLM though it did under HKCU. However your script still did not avoid the security.

Comment: This is *terrible* advice. Not only does it at best temporarily mitigate the symptom (group policies are re-applied periodically, by default every 90-120 minutes), it also usually means you're violating corporate policies, which may result in legal action.

Answer (score 7):

Even if @Ansgar Wiechers's Answer doesn't work.. Then there can be issue with you MachinePolicy Scope. So there can be one workaround for that issue is..
Edit the Registry Value for the ExecutionPolicy Key at

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE -> SOFTWARE  -> Policies -> Microsoft -> Windows ->
>   Powershell

it worked for me to execute ps script after trying out so many solutions.

Comment: This just repeats (in less detail) the answer from Andry 4 years prior.

Answer (score 6):

If you are running into this with visual studio 2015 recently, check if there are any updates for nuget package manager in tools > extensions and updates>

Comment: Visual Studio updates are not related to the PowerShell Execution Policy in any way.

Answer (score 6):

Add the following to a file named `psa.cmd` and put in a folder included your PATH :

```
POWERSHELL -Command "$enccmd=[Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes((Get-Content '%1' | Out-String)));POWERSHELL -EncodedCommand $enccmd"
```

Now you can run any powershell script as in:

```
psa script.ps1
```

Comment: Good solution.  Visual Studio 2015 running the scripts natively sometimes works and sometimes hangs.  This works every time.  Thanks Marc

Answer (score 2):

I just did:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope Process -Force
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

and it worked

Answer (score -1):

Last time I jumped into this issue the following code fixed it. Don't forget to run terminal with Administrator priviliges and rerun it before executing script.

```
Set-ItemProperty -path "Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell" EnableScripts 1
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is how I fixed mine:
First, I run  **Get-ExecutionPolicy -List** which lists out the scopes and their current state.

```
    Scope ExecutionPolicy
    ----- ---------------
MachinePolicy       Undefined
   UserPolicy       Undefined
      Process       Undefined
  CurrentUser       Undefined
 LocalMachine       Undefined
```

As you can see all the scopes are undefined, and I think that is why I was not able to run any script on PowerShell. Now all I have to do is to make the CurrentUser scope unrestricted and to do this, I run **Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser -Force**.

But also try setting the **CurrentUser** scope to Restricted and then back to Unrestricted, in case you run into any problems.

```
ExecutionPolicy Restricted -Scope CurrentUser -Force
ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser -Force
```

Comment: This just repeats the accepted answer (in less detail).

Answer (score -3):

Try this if you having problems again and again although changed the restrictions.: **Right click on the windows logo** > select **Powershell(admin)** and then you can execute commands.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).