# ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system

Tags: c#, powershell

I try to run `powershell` script from c#.

First i set the `ExecutionPolicy` to `Unrestricted` and the script is running now from `PowerShell ISE`.

Now this is c# my code:

```
class Program
{
    private static PowerShell ps;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ps = PowerShell.Create();
        string ps1File = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "script.ps1");
        ExecuteScript(ps1File);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void ExecuteScript(string script)
    {
        try
        {
            ps.AddScript(script);
            Collection<PSObject> results = ps.Invoke();
            Console.WriteLine("Output:");
            foreach (var psObject in results)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(psObject);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Non-terminating errors:");
            foreach (ErrorRecord err in ps.Streams.Error)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(err.ToString());
            }
        }
        catch (RuntimeException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Terminating error:");
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

And the output is:

> ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this
>   system. For more informationm see about_Execution_Policies at
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.

Comment: Have you tried to set the policy scope to Local machine? 'Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope LocalMachine -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted'

Comment: Run `Get-ExecutionPolicy -List` and edit your question with the results. This command will show you the different Scope's and their ExecutionPolicy setting.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work I'm afraid, but just to be clear, this is NOT at command line level, as I'm able to run on a remote desktop without problems.

Comment: Related documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-executionpolicy?view=powershell-7.3

Answer (score 1281):

This could be due to the current user having an undefined `ExecutionPolicy`.

In PowerShell *as Administrator*, you could try the following:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

Comment: BTW, this should be executed in `Powershell`, not windows's cmd.

Comment: @Tom: any security concern after changing this ?, should we set back this to the restricted or more safe value when our change or work is done ?? (reading the current value and set it back to it when work done ?)

Comment: @HDJEMAI, I guess this depends on what context you are running this. `Unrestricted` means you can run all scripts. Another option to this would be to set the execution policy to `RemoteSigned` as this will allow `Allow local scripts and remote signed scripts` but depending on the application and what it is doing this may still throw the same error. I think your approach is valid in terms of security and you could always read what the policy is before hand using `Get-ExecutionPloicy`. Although this being said the scope is the current user so the risk in my opinion is small. I hope this helps.

Comment: "Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted" is working, thanks @tom

Comment: I would also vouch for `RemoteSigned`. `Unrestricted` could be unnecessary allowing.

Comment: How to restrict back?

Comment: saved me the trouble of reading through https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-7.1

Comment: This worked. Make sure you are in powershell before executing this command

Comment: I did not need to start Powershell as Admin to change this, I could be in Powershell with my non-Admin user instead.

Comment: If you have a particular project running in VSCode, go for this command - `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope Process`. The plus side of this command is that the execution policy remains in the default state on the system but only changes for a particular process. There isn't any security concern when you use this command.

Answer (score 169):

Open powershell in administrative mode 
and run the following command

> `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned`

Comment: This should be accepted answer, as other answers can be insecure and cause problems.

Comment: How about?
`Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned`
This worked for me and limits the scope to the current user.

Comment: @abrar

Depends on what you want to achieve with your shell script and the requirement you are working on per say.

You can use either of the way if it does the job and does not raise any concerns. 

It's all depend on project requirements. What worked for you may not work for me or vice versa under some scenarios/ constraint. 

We all have choice to optimize the solution as per our need.

Comment: I already executed the accepted answer -,-

Comment: @ShahidKamal how are they insecure? Microsoft themselves say execution policy is [not](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Execution_Policies) a security feature.

Comment: @gargoylebident It definitely is. You can see that explained in the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Execution_Policies?view=powershell-7.2#unrestricted) you sent: "Unsigned scripts can run. There is a risk of running malicious scripts."

Answer (score 60):

Run this code in your powershell or cmd

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Bypass
```

Comment: Works for other languages (editing an Ionic app right now) too!

Comment: Worked for me as well, ran inside VIsual Studio Code terminal in order to get Typescript running using tsc command

Answer (score 58):

Try this command in terminal(Visual Studio Code terminal or any IDE you are using) and problem will solve

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope CurrentUser
```

note : don't change CurrentUser to your username

Comment: ran on IntelliJ Idea terminal and it worked. Thanks :)

Comment: Works in VSCODE, Thanks!

Comment: worked for me vscode react native

Comment: Work for me, Thanks! using SharePoint Online Management Shell!

Answer (score 44):

If you are using visual studio code:

1. Open terminal
2. Run the command: Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
3. Then run the command protractor conf.js

This is related to protractor test script execution related and I faced the same issue and it was resolved like this.

Answer (score 38):

go to system settings -> Update & Security -> For Developers -> PowerShell

apply the following option

[image]

Comment: i tried to open terminal and type vue create new-project and it worked :). thank you for suggestion

Comment: I followed the whole process and it started working. Thanks

Comment: all you are doing indirectly is: ** Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned **

Comment: @Digambernegi sure :)

Comment: this should be ticked as the permanent solution

Comment: Thanks for this! Some of the other answers list commands that do the same thing. The fact that this is listed in a "For developers" section gives me a bit more peace of mind though.

Comment: I tried every thing and finally only this solved the problem!. Thanks for posting this solution.

Answer (score 21):

**Open VS Code terminal and run the following script:**

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

Comment: How does the guidance in this answer differ from the guidance in the most voted up answer posted years ago?

Comment: for some people, this command is working only in vs code terminal. not in window termnal

Answer (score 16):

1. close your current command prompt or vs code (terminal)
2. open PowerShell in Admin mode
3. run this command inside PowerShell

> **Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted**

4. answer   **Y**   or  **A** (if you want to give access to all users)
5. now open command prompt or vs code or whatever you like to run your project

Comment: This fixed it for me. In my case, I couldn't run Angular CLI commands inside of VSCode's integrated terminal (Powershell). I didn't have to close or restart my terminal, it just worked immediately after the command.

Comment: Works for Windows 11 users!

Answer (score 12):

The following three steps are used to fix  Running Scripts is disabled on this System error

Step1 : To fix this kind of problem, we have to start power shell in administrator mode.

Step2 : Type the following command set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned 
Step3: Press Y for your Confirmation.

Visit the following for more information https://youtu.be/J_596H-sWsk

Answer (score 12):

Paste this code in your terminal

(Visual Studio Code terminal or any IDE you are using)

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

Press Enter

Enjoy :)

Answer (score 10):

Another solution is Remove ng.ps1 from the directory C:\Users%username%\AppData\Roaming\npm\ and clearing the npm cache

Comment: I had the same error with a npm module and this is the solution I like best. If you remove the .ps1 file, it will happly use one of the other two scripts (eg. the .cmd on Windows, the one without extension otherwise), and you don't have to change you security configuration

Comment: Did the same for yarn.ps1, works perfect! Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Open PowerShell in administrative mode and run the following command

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

Comment: Isn't this a big security issue?

Comment: no sure but you are setting it for current user only so i didn't think that it would be

Comment: also, Microsoft themselves says execution policy is not a security feature.

Answer (score 7):

open windows powershell in administrator mode and run the following command and its work VOILA!!

> Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned

Answer (score 7):

This is the best way I've been able to fix it

It is as follows:

1. First, Open PowerShell with Run as Administrator.
2. Then, run this command in PowerShell

   **Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned**
3. After that type Y and press Enter.
4. Reopen or Restart
5. Done! working well!

Comment: Getting this below error :-
--watch/-w can be omitted, JSON Server 1+ watches for file changes by default
File db.json not found

Answer (score 6):

The PowerShell execution policy is default set to Restricted. You can change the PowerShell execution policies with Set-ExecutionPolicy cmdlet. To run outside script set policy to RemoteSigned.

PS C:> Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned 
Below is the list of four different execution policies in PowerShell

Restricted – No scripts can be run.
AllSigned – Only scripts signed by a trusted publisher can be run.
RemoteSigned – Downloaded scripts must be signed by a trusted publisher.
Unrestricted – All Windows PowerShell scripts can be run.

Answer (score 5):

This one need to be used in every shell:

`Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer (Windows 10 for me  - Works). Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

For **Windows 11** go to

system settings -> Privacy & Security -> Choose `For Developers` tile under Security -> Scroll down to Powershell.

[image]

By default the checkbox is checked. If you want to set that click Apply and it set the execution policy to `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser`. Then checkbox and Apply button get disabled.

If you want to change the policy again, need to run the Powershell as an Administrator and execute the desired policy.

Sometimes you may not able to change the policy based on the scope and it might get below error.

For an example if you are try to set to the default policy using `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Restricted -Scope LocalMachine` you may get

[image]

To fix this you may need to follow [fix-windows-powershell-updated-your-execution-policy-successfully, but the setting is overridden by a policy defined at a more specific scope](https://www.itexperience.net/fix-windows-powershell-updated-your-execution-policy-successfully/)
or check answers in here. [cannot change the Execution Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27753917/how-do-you-successfully-change-execution-policy-and-enable-execution-of-powershe)

Answer (score 3):

Let me improve this answer with the visuals. I took 3 steps and fixed this problem.

**Step #1.** I opened Windows PowerShell in admin mode (on windows searchbar search for Windows PowerShell) > right click choose the option Run as administrator.  You will be prompted again just click on OK

[image]

**Step #2** Run this command ****Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted****

[image]

**type Y**

**Step 3:** Close the terminal and move back to where you were previsouly running the command and test it. Like in my case I was having a problem when doing sass -- watch as you can see it now works

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this error:

```
 ng : File C:\Users\Nisha Jain\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng.ps1 cannot be loaded 
 because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more        
 information, see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/? 
 LinkID=135170.
   At line:1 char:1
   + ng serve
   + ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

Just delete this file  ng.ps1

```
   Path is : C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng.ps1
```

It works fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

The more secure one should be (typed at an admin Powershell terminal):

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

Each case needs a thorough analysis to not **expose your system to threats**.

### RemoteSigned

- The default execution policy for Windows server computers.
- Scripts can run.
- Requires a digital signature from a trusted publisher on scripts and configuration files that are downloaded from the internet which includes email and instant messaging programs.
- Doesn't require digital signatures on scripts that are written on the local computer and not downloaded from the internet.
- Runs scripts that are downloaded from the internet and not signed, if the scripts are unblocked, such as by using the Unblock-File cmdlet.
- Risks running unsigned scripts from sources other than the internet and signed scripts that could be malicious.

Default

- Sets the default execution policy.
- Restricted for Windows clients.
- RemoteSigned for Windows servers.

[take a look at all policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-7.4)

In my case, I needed to allow my ***azurite*** (Azure Storage Emulator) script to run, I installed it using ***npm***.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I faced the same issue that `running-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system` when I was trying to deploy an app on the `netlify`

Below cmd worked for me.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope CurrentUser
```

Answer (score -1):

Open the windows powershell or cmd and just paste the following command. If it ask for further confirmation just enter Yes`Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned`

below should appear

```
`Execution Policy Change
```

The execution policy helps protect you from scripts that you do not trust. Changing the execution policy might expose
you to the security risks described in the about_Execution_Policies help topic at
https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170. Do you want to change the execution policy?
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "N"): Yes
PS C:\Users\Tessact01>`