# creating a server and using nodemon but it shows error

Tags: node.js, server, nodemon

nodemon : File C:\Users\shara\AppData\Roaming\npm\nodemon.ps1 cannot be loaded
because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see
about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1

Answer (score 0):

This is probably an execution policy issue as the error suggests.

See answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49112322/10290918).