# cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

It was working fine and then I got an error. After solving it, I still keep getting this error, regardless of whatever project it is.

Output:

```
& : File C:\Users\pc\Documents\python\venv\Scripts\Activate.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is 
    disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at 
    https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
    At line:1 char:3
    + & c:/Users/pc/Documents/python/venv/Scripts/Activate.ps1
    +   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException       
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccessenter code here
```

Comment: possible duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/a/49112322/13126651

Comment: thanks i saw it and it solved the problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41117421/ps1-cannot-be-loaded-because-running-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system)

Comment: Open PowerShell as an Administrator: Search for PowerShell in the Start menu, right-click on it, and select "Run as administrator".
Change the Execution Policy: Run the following command:
<Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned>
PowerShell will ask you to confirm the change to the execution policy setting. Type Y and press Enter to confirm.
Try activating your environment again: Now, try to run the activate script for your Python environment again.

Answer (score 201):

This is because the user your running the script as has a undefined `ExecutionPolicy` You could fix this by running the following in powershell:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

Comment: It works for me for running my virtual environment in vs code.

Comment: This does not work for me, `Get-ExecutionPolicy` returns `Unrestricted`, but the error remains the same.

Comment: I was stuck because of this, finally working now!

Comment: It works also for me.

Comment: Is it safe to use this method?

Comment: Working for me in Pycharm 2022.3 (Professional Edition).

Comment: I am worried, is it safe to set running scripts to unrestricted?

Comment: @enthu see the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/70600265/1545084 below:
"Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser"

Comment: It Is working for me too in 2023, windows 10

Comment: Thanks, simple and effective answer! It works for me

Answer (score 26):

If you are getting error like this,

[image]

We can resolve that using the following steps,

- Get the status of current `ExecutionPolicy` by the command below:

  ```
  Get-ExecutionPolicy
  ```

  By default it is Restricted. To allow the execution of PowerShell scripts we need to set this ExecutionPolicy either as Unrestricted or Bypass.
- We can set the policy for Current User as `Bypass` by using any of the below PowerShell commands:

  ```
  Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force
  Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Force
  ```

  Unrestricted policy loads all configuration files and runs all scripts. If you run an unsigned script that was downloaded from the Internet, you are prompted for permission before it runs.

  Whereas in Bypass policy, nothing is blocked and there are no warnings or prompts during script execution. Bypass `ExecutionPolicy` is more relaxed than `Unrestricted`.

Answer (score 22):

Might also wanna consider setting it to:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser
```

You'll get a message about Execution Policy change (obviously) to which I said "A" for yes to all. Select what works best for you.

This should allow you to run your own scripts but any originating from anywhere else will require approval.

*above post edited for clarity

Comment: hi please add the command line for `Remote-Signed` i believe this is a better solution than `Unrestricted` :)

Answer (score 12):

Just type this in the powershell

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

and it will be enabled

Answer (score 5):

Just open Windows Powershell as administrator and execute this command `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force`. Issue will be resolved and you can activate it in VS code or CMD.

Answer (score 4):

```
step 1: -Press the windows-button on your keyboard.
step 2: -Type ‘PowerShell’
step 3: -Right-click Windows PowerShell
step 4: -Click Run as Administrator
step 5: -Run the following command and confirm with ‘Y’
Try this. 

Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope LocalMachine
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me (Win11, PowerShell as Admin):

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser

Unblock-File (Join-Path $env:PYENV 'bin/pyenv.ps1')
```

Answer (score 1):

first run:

```
Get-ExecutionPolicy
```

then run:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force
```

Answer (score 0):

step 1: -Press the windows-button on your keyboard.

step 2: -Type ‘PowerShell’

step 3: -Right-click Windows PowerShell

step 4: -Click Run as Administrator

step 5: -Run the following command and confirm with ‘Y’
Try this.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope LocalMachine
```

Answer (score 0):

Because it is restricted. So type this command in PowerShell
`Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted`

Answer (score -1):

workon "namefolder"

.\venv\scripts\activate

Comment: PLease give explanantion and details .. os ... langage ... commands .. error message copy ...

Answer (score -1):

As it is written in the documentation of [pyenv-win github](https://github.com/pyenv-win/pyenv-win/blob/master/docs/installation.md#powershell)

If you are getting any UnauthorizedAccess error as below then start Windows PowerShell with the "Run as administrator" option and run `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope LocalMachine`, now re-run the above installation command.