# How to open live server from the terminal in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am very new to coding and am currently learning Javascript. I cant seem to open the liveserver from my terminal in VSCode.

I get the below message:

```
////
live-server : The term 'live-server' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that     
the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ live-server
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (live-server:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException 
////
```

Pls help.

Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about LiveServer extension?

Comment: Yes I am talking about the Live Server extension in Visual Studio Code.

Comment: What are you typing into your terminal?

Comment: I downloaded Node.js and managed it. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, you should verify that node.js is installed.

```
node -v
```

Then install the `live-server` package:

```
npm install -g live-server
```

If you still had issue related to (....ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system..... ) run this script in powershell:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

good luck!
[installing live server](https://findanyanswer.com/how-do-you-use-vs-code-live-server)
[restricted access to run script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41117421/ps1-cannot-be-loaded-because-running-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system)