# How to setup very first React Native app with expo

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, powershell, expo

I've tried commands:

```
npm i -g expo-cli
expo init uber
```

The error:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

- Switch to cmd
  or
- Run this command

  Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Bypass

This command is going to work untill you close the PS, if you reopen it, you should pass it again, there is a very big thread for this, take a look:
[ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41117421/ps1-cannot-be-loaded-because-running-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system)

Comment: BIngo. Thank You Buddy