# I can't install node sass

Tags: css, node.js, sass

When I write: `sass --watch src/scss:dist/css`

I am getting this error

> npm\sass.ps1 cannot be loaded because of running scripts is disabled on the system

[image]

[image]

Comment: have you tried running it in a powershell as admin?

Comment: Yes. it didnt work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41117421/ps1-cannot-be-loaded-because-running-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system)