# How to fix this error: error TS2456: Type alias 'Geometry' circularly references itself?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, maven

I have a maven project in html, css and typescript. When I run the command: mvn clean install, I have this error:

```
ERROR in node_modules/@types/geojson/index.d.ts(79,13): error TS2456: Type alias 'Geometry' circularly references itself.

[ERROR] Command execution failed.
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:404)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:166)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine(ExecMojo.java:764)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine(ExecMojo.java:711)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute(ExecMojo.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 02:35 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-07-19T09:23:23+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/241M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:exec (angular-cli build) on project TrimlyAngular: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:exec (angular-cli build) on project TrimlyAngular: Command execution failed.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Command execution failed.
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute(ExecMojo.java:302)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:404)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:166)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine(ExecMojo.java:764)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine(ExecMojo.java:711)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute(ExecMojo.java:289)
    ... 22 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

There is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "project-name",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "node --max_old_space_size=8192 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod --aot=true --base-href",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "fixture-backend": "node fixture-server/fixture-server.js",
    "fixture-frontend": "ng serve --proxy-conf fixture-server/fixture-proxy-conf.json",
    "start-fixture": " concurrently  \"npm run fixture-backend\" \"npm run fixture-frontend\" "
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.8.9",
    "@angular/animations": "^6.1.10",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.10",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.1.10",
    "@angular/http": "^6.1.10",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.1.10",
    "@angular/material": "^5.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.10",
    "@angular/router": "^6.1.10",
    "@babel/core": "^7.10.2",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.10.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.10.1",
    "@beyerleinf/ngx-dnd": "^6.0.4",
    "@gooddata/react-components": "^7.6.1",
    "@recogito/annotorious-openseadragon": "^2.0.5",
    "@recogito/recogito-client-core": "^0.1.5",
    "@swimlane/dragula": "^3.8.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-dnd": "^5.1.0",
    "@types/cropperjs": "^1.3.0",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.36",
    "angular-font-awesome": "^3.1.2",
    "angular-material": "^1.1.7",
    "angular-tree-component": "^7.2.1",
    "angular2-datetimepicker": "^1.1.1",
    "axiom-ngx-tree": "^1.0.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "bowser": "^2.11.0",
    "classlist.js": "1.1.20150312",
    "concurrently": "^5.2.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.5",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "cropperjs": "^1.5.9",
    "crypto-js": "^3.3.0",
    "d3": "^4.13.0",
    "dpdm": "^3.5.0",
    "exifr": "^7.1.3",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "invariant": "^2.2.4",
    "ionic2-rating": "^1.2.2",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "levon-angular-star-rating": "^3.0.0",
    "mime": "^2.4.6",
    "missing": "0.0.1",
    "ng-click-outside": "^4.0.0",
    "ng-pick-datetime": "^5.2.6",
    "ng2-nouislider": "^1.7.7",
    "ng2-pdfjs-viewer": "^3.2.2",
    "ngx-color": "7.0.0",
    "ngx-cookie": "^3.0.1",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^1.0.10",
    "ngx-datatable-with-ie-fix": "^8.0.0",
    "ngx-drag-and-drop-lists": "1.1.7",
    "ngx-notification-bar": "^0.1.4",
    "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^5.3.5",
    "ngx-tree-dnd": "^2.6.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.0.0",
    "nouislider": "^11.0.3",
    "npm-install-missing": "^0.1.4",
    "openseadragon": "^2.4.2",
    "phantomjs": "^2.1.7",
    "rater-js": "^0.5.8",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.0.0-rc.0",
    "ts-md5": "^1.2.7",
    "uuid": "^8.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^6.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.1.10",
    "@types/d3": "^4.13.12",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "husky": "^4.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^3.1.4",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.2",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-istanbul-preprocessor": "0.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "^1.2.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.4",
    "madge": "^3.12.0",
    "prettier": "^2.1.2",
    "pretty-quick": "^3.1.0",
    "protractor": "^5.1.2",
    "sass-resources-loader": "^2.0.3",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "^5.9.1",
    "tslint-config-prettier": "^1.18.0",
    "tslint-etc": "^1.10.1",
    "typescript": "~2.9.2"
  }
}
```

I have searched on Internet and I already done this:

- Delete package-lock.json and node_modules folder and then run npm install ;
- Modify the typescript version in package.json.

Thank you by advance for your help.

Comment: That's quite the dependency list you got there. Angular and React and JQuery, not to mention all the rest.

Comment: The problem is coming form your `geojson` package. Since you are using TS, you should use a different library, as noted in the [readme](https://github.com/caseycesari/GeoJSON.js) of `geojson`

Comment: Thank you @MichaelDoye , but this library `geojson` is not in my package.json. What should I do exactly?

Comment: I tried to add geojson in the package.json but it doesn't change the issue. So I suppose this dependency is comming from another one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For my part, there were a dependency 'geojson' which was called by something and always updated. A recent update change and broke my project. So I add this dependency with the specific version in the package.json file and the problem was resolved.

```
"@types/geojson": "7946.0.8"
```

Edit : like said MaciejLisCK, after that you need to call npm install.

Comment: remember to call `npm install` after change

Comment: in my case I had to use that specific version, `7946.0.8`. Using `7946.0.10` broke my build

Answer (score 5):

For me the problem was due to geojson embed in another dependency wich didn't specify the version.
I add this to my `package.json` to solve the problem. I didn't work for me without the `"resolutions"` section.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@types/geojson": "7946.0.8"
},
"resolutions": {
    "@types/geojson": "7946.0.8"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether you are using latest angular and node versions, some time it's helpful to use latest version. it will take care of the older version and resolve some issues.
Check whether ng command is accessible without any errors in script starting. if ng command is not working then check execution policy.
[ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41117421/ps1-cannot-be-loaded-because-running-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system)

The global latest angular cli will use the needed cli local version automatically with a yellow message.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it inside package.json in **"@types/geojson": "^7946.0.10"** i deleted (^) showing finally like that: **"@types/geojson": "7946.0.10"** without (^).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).