# nodemon occuring issue while command

Tags: node.js, nodemon

nodemon : File C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Roaming\npm\nodemon.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For
more information, see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1

- nodemon index.js
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
  ```

nodemon : File C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Roaming\npm\nodemon.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For
more information, see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1

- nodemon index.js
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
  ```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41117421/ps1-cannot-be-loaded-because-running-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system)

Comment: yes exactly any solution

Comment: See [the top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49112322/15359157)?