# Package Manager console command without PowerShell access

Tags: entity-framework, powershell, migration

to work with EntityFramework Migration, I need to have access to PowerShell, which I don't have in my company for some security reasons.

is there any way to run these command, without have access to PowerShell?

here is the error get when I start Package Manager Console[image]

Comment: Well, talk to your admins/manager about this. The company decided on a policy. If you need PowerShell to do the job you were hired for it's their job to revise the policy, not your job to work around it.

Comment: they proposed to work on a remote server, but remote server reduced my performance by 50% at least. anyway, forget about the policy, is there any way to program migration and other EF stuff without interacting with PowerShell or not?

Comment: Are you _sure_ that it is their policy to block powershell in this way and did you try @Priyanka solution? `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser`

Comment: I tried, but not worked for me, it's been restricted through group policy.

Answer (score 1):

follow this steps :

1. Run Powershell with administrator privilege
2. Type this command  :

   Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Force
3. Press Enter
4. Restart you're program

and if u don't have access to powershell follow this way :

1. go to Regedit.exe and follow this path :

   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFWARE\microsoft\powershell\1\shelllds\microsoft.powershell\executionpolicy

and change of this string value Bypass

2. go to this address :

   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFWARE\microsoft\powershell\1\shelllds\Scripted.diagnostic\executionpolicy

and change this value to bypass

Comment: not useful, the powershell has been restricted through Group Policy, I can't run it. I need a solution to run EF command without PowerShell, kinda programming it

Comment: @vahid : agha vahid too rahe dovvomi ke neveshtam powershell run nemishe faghat registry hast . amma age manzooretoon nuget hast oon commandash tahte powershell run mishe .

Comment: khob bade dastkariye registry ham baz nemitunam powershell ro run konam, va vaghti powershell natune ejra beshe (chon az tu GroupPolicy baste shode) nemitunam command haye package manager ro run konam. man donbale rahi hastam betunam masalan add-migration ro bedune niaz be power shell run konam, zaheran ye rahi hast beshe tu visual studio add-on nevesht bara in kar

Comment: are ye add-on hast ammma kar nakardam age chizi didam minvistam baratoon . amma be default az powershell estefade mikone .

Comment: albate ye mozoo ham hast in mostaghiman az powershell estefade nemikone az ye kernel mesle oon estefade mikone . yani resource hashoon ro az ye ja migiran mesle policy , ...

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set the execution policy. By default it's restricted that's what blocking the execution. Just run from PowerShell command prompt!

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

If you don't have admin rights, you can set the policy just for yourself!

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser
```

Remember to run them as command not as a script.

Comment: That only works if the execution policy isn't set via policy. [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27755459/1630171).