# Set-ExecutionPolicy Error when not being called

Tags: powershell, executionpolicy

When I run any script from a .ps1 file on my server I receive an error about the `Set-ExcutionPolicy` being successful but being overridden by a higher scope.
However none of the code I am running has anything to do with execution policies or changing them. Any Idea why I'm getting this error?

This is on a Windows 2012 R2 server where execution policy for all levels is set to remote signed. I'm running on PowerShell V4.0

If I open PowerShell or the ISE and type in the command it completes without showing the error it only occurs when I try and run a script from a .ps1 file.

This is the error:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy : Windows PowerShell updated your execution policy
successfully, but the setting is overridden by a policy defined at a more
specific scope.  Due to the override, your shell will retain its current
effective execution policy of RemoteSigned. Type "Get-ExecutionPolicy -List"
to view your execution policy settings. For more information please see
"Get-Help Set-ExecutionPolicy".
At line:1 char:46
+ if((Get-ExecutionPolicy ) -ne 'AllSigned') { Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process  ...
+                                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (:) [Set-ExecutionPolicy], SecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExecutionPolicyOverride,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetExecutionPolicyCommand
```

Comment: It occurs when I run any powershell saved script. It can be as simply as get-services it still shows the error. I can't share many details as this is a work server.

Comment: Show the actual error.  It is likely that you've got some group policy object, or other restrictions in place, from an enterprise security perspective.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27755459/1630171).

Comment: Besides, what do you mean *"none of the code I am running has anything to do with execution policies or changing them"* when the error clearly shows you're running `Set-ExecutionPolicy` (or at least trying to)?

Comment: have you looked into ALL of your various profiles? the one used for running scripts is likely the console profile ... and it may have a script in it that creates the error you show.

Comment: You probably have a GPO that set the executionPolicy

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - This is why I'm asking the question. I'm seeing this error when I run a saved script that contains a code as simple as 1 line saying {get-services}. Also the related post isn't related to my issue. I understand how to set my execution policy and the way scope works I'm confused as to why I see this error when I'm not trying to change the policy at all.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Thanks I will have a look at the Profile running the script

Comment: @FrédéricBonneau. I know that we have a GPO that sets the execution policy at the highest two scopes. I'm just wondering why me running a script is making it think I want to change this.

Comment: Do you get the same error if you launch `powershell.exe -NoProfile -NoExit` from CMD or the Run dialog and then run a script in that instance?

Comment: No I don't see the error if I run it from a CMD instance.

Comment: @Tourius - if running it with `-NoProfile` avoids the error ... then the source is almost  certainly in the profile being used by `powershell.exe`. time to start digging thru those files! [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *"Run with PowerShell"* context menu entry for .ps1 files invokes the following commandline:

```
"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" "-Command" "if((Get-ExecutionPolicy ) -ne 'AllSigned') { Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process Bypass }; & '%1'"
```

It's stored in the registry key `HKCU\Microsoft.PowerShellScript.1\Shell\0\Command`. Since you have the execution policy defined via Group Policy, setting a conflicting execution policy in the Process scope whenever you're running a PowerShell script via its context menu causes the error you observed.

Change the commandline in the registry to something like this:

```
"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -File "%L"
```

and the error will disappear.