# Run PowerShell script by double clicking a file

Tags: powershell, double-click

I'm trying to run this script by double clicking the file:

```
    $notifyParams = @{title="XXXX";content="New Tasks Available!"}
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://hook.notify17.net/api/raw/XXXXX -Method POST -Body $notifyParams
```

I want another program to activate it automatically so Right-click> Run with Powershell won't help me.

I have tried everything suggested in this thread, nothing seems to help:
[Is there a way to make a PowerShell script work by double clicking a .ps1 file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10137146/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-powershell-script-work-by-double-clicking-a-ps1-file)

Only Right-click> Run with Powershell actually runs the script.

I have no actual knowledge in PowerShell and I did not wrote it myself, I just need to run it.

Comment: The solutions in that thread you've linked should work. When you try the accepted answer (including the bit in comments about ExecutionPolicy) what happens?

Comment: Do you get an error?

Comment: The window opens and close briefly and that's it, with every method mentioned in the thread.

Comment: Use the -noexit flag in the shortcut to keep the window open, that should let you see the text

Answer (score 0):

I changed the group policy for the execution policy (https://stackoverflow.com/a/27753927/15681745) and it worked with a cmd file with this script

```
    ::====================================================================
:: Powershell script launcher
::=====================================================================
:MAIN
    @echo off
    for /f "tokens=*" %%p in ("%~p0") do set SCRIPT_PATH=%%p
    pushd "%SCRIPT_PATH%"

    powershell.exe -sta -c "& {.\%~n0.ps1 %*}"

    popd
    set SCRIPT_PATH=
    pause
```

Comment: If the execution policy was the problem then you can just use `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` on your shortcut unless you actually want to run your script with cmd