# How can change ExecutionPolicy in Powershell,how can solve this error

Tags: powershell-2.0, environment, executionpolicy

[image]
scrrenshot

I want to change the execution policy for create virtual env in python ,screenshot of the error, how can solve it

Comment: Not sure why this is tagged as python, don't see any python related content here. Hence removing ``python`` tag

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you successfully change execution policy and enable execution of PowerShell scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27753917/how-do-you-successfully-change-execution-policy-and-enable-execution-of-powershe)