# change execution policy and enable execution of PowerShell scripts

Tags: azure, powershell, installation, windows-installer, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

How can I change the policy that will allow me to run the PowerShell script on my machine?
[PowerShell screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXp5M.png)

I have tried checking the solution described there:

[How do you successfully change execution policy and enable execution of PowerShell scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27753917/how-do-you-successfully-change-execution-policy-and-enable-execution-of-powershe)

I changed the settings in
MMC (Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components)
and
regedit (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE -> SOFTWARE -> Policies -> Microsoft -> Windows -> Powershell)

but all the time I am getting that error on the attached screen

Set-ExecutionPolicy : Windows PowerShell updated your execution policy successfully, but the setting is overridden by a
policy defined at a more specific scope.  Due to the override, your shell will retain its current effective execution
policy of RemoteSigned. Type "Get-ExecutionPolicy -List" to view your execution policy settings. For more information p
p lease see "Get-Help Set-ExecutionPolicy".
At line:1 char:46

- ...  -ne 'AllSigned') { Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process Bypass }; & 'C ...
- ```
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (:) [Set-ExecutionPolicy], SecurityException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExecutionPolicyOverride,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetExecutionPolicyCommand

[How do you successfully change execution policy and enable execution of PowerShell scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27753917/how-do-you-successfully-change-execution-policy-and-enable-execution-of-powershe)

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE -> SOFTWARE -> Policies -> Microsoft -> Windows -> Powershell
changed to "ByPass"

Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components
Turn Script execution: enabled
Execution policy: allow all scripts

Answer (score 1):

Try this and work up.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process
```

You can try other values for scope.

```
Get-Help Set-ExecutionPolicy -Parameter scope
```

Get the values for the enum listed for that parametr:

```
[Microsoft.PowerShell.ExecutionPolicyScope]::GetValues([Microsoft.PowerShell.ExecutionPolicyScope])
```

Comment: it worked. But now if I have few PowerShell scripts and I want to create a sequence and run them one by one after they are finished how can I do that?

for example I have three scripts one.ps1, two.ps2, three.ps1 and I want a sequence:
one.ps1 - wait for the end and then run next,
two.ps1 - wait for the end and then run next,
three.ps1

Comment: Probably depends on what scope worked for you.  Generally if you set it in a session, it will apply to that session and children so you can just call the three scripts.

Answer (score 0):

- You've (successfully) updated your script [execution policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Execution_Policies) via a GPO (Group Policy Object; via MMC, as described in your question).
- GPO-based execution policies have the highest precedence among all the scopes in which you can set a policy; `Get-ExecutionPolicy -List` shows the scopes in descending order of precedence.
- Your error message shows an attempt to set the execution policy for the *current process* (`-Scope Process`).
- Because an execution policy in the process scope is *overridden* by GPO-based execution policies, the process-level attempt is *ineffective*, and that's what the error message is trying to tell you.
- You can *ignore* the error if the GPO-based execution policy is still permissive enough to allow you to run your script, but I suspect that the process-level attempt to set the execution policy stems from running your scripts *via File Explorer's context menu*, whose invocation command is - unfortunately - defined that way.

  - You can try to modify the invocation command via the registry (`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Microsoft.PowerShellScript.1\shell\0\Command`) and remove the `Set-ExecutionPolicy` call from it.