How to run script with elevated privileges on Shutdown using gpedit.msc on Windows 11?
I can't run a bat file on Shutdown on Windows 11.
runAs.bat:
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\Machine\Scripts\Shutdown\changeComputerName.ps1""' -Verb RunAs}"

changeComputerName.ps1:
$computerName = -join ((97..122) | Get-Random -Count 15 | ForEach-Object {[char]$_})
Rename-Computer $computerName

They are both located in:
C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\Machine\Scripts\Shutdown\

The Shutdown properties is set to run the runAs.bat file which in turn runs a PowerShell process with elevated privileges to change the computer name.
When running the bat file from the terminal, it asks for elevated privileges and then it runs successfully.
Where should I be looking for error/debug info?
Thanks

This is a direct implication of UAC (user account control): "With UAC, each application that requires the administrator access token must prompt the end user for consent". Anyway arround that from a user account would be a security issue. You might consider using a special account as the SYSTEM account.

@iRon Thanks for your reply. I was able to achieve what I wanted by creating a Scheduled Task and have it run on every login. Which works for me.

As an aside: There's generally no reason to use "& { ... }" in order to invoke code passed to PowerShell's CLI via the -Command (-c) parameter - just use "..." directly. Older versions of the CLI documentation erroneously suggested that & { ... } is required, but this has since been corrected.

I was able to get passed this UAC(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/application-security/application-control/user-account-control/how-it-works) limitation by creating a Scheduled Task which runs the .bat file with "Run with highest privileges" checked in the General Tab. The script runs on every logon of every user to the machine.
I also disabled UAC at the beginning and renabled it at the end of my powershell script. By using this PowerShell line:
Set-ItemProperty -Path REGISTRY::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System -Name ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin -Value 0


I suggest avoiding even temporary modification of UAC policies. Your original approach can be made to work without compromising security, as detailed in my answer.


You don't need a wrapper batch file in order to execute a PowerShell script on shutdown via the relevant GPO (Group Policy Object) at Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Scripts (Startup/Shutdown), item Shutdown in the Group Policy Editor (invoke it with gpedit.msc):

In the Properties dialog, there is a PowerShell Scripts tab, where you can directly specify a .ps1 file, which is implicitly invoked as:

powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File C:\path\to\your\script.ps1

Note: While it makes sense to place such script files in C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\Machine\Scripts\Shutdown, doing so is not strictly required: you're free to reference script files in other locations.



The invocation happens in the context of the built-in, highly privileged NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM account, which, in effect, implicitly amounts to execution with elevation.



Therefore, all you need to do is to directly pick your C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\Machine\Scripts\Shutdown\changeComputerName.ps1 script as to be executed on shutdown, as described above.



As for what you tried:
Most likely, the only problem with your own approach was neglecting to use Start-Process's -Wait switch to ensure synchronous execution.

While requesting elevation with -Verb RunAs quietly succeeds if the calling process itself is already elevated (i.e., no UAC dialog is triggered in that case), it still runs the process (in a new window and) asynchronously by default - except if -Wait is also specified.

Thus, the asynchronously launched process may not have gotten a chance to execute before the shutdown was initiated.


That said, it is much simpler to specify the target .ps1 directly - without the need for an explicit call to powershell.exe, the Windows PowerShell CLI, and a nested Start-Process call -  as shown in the top section.

Thanks for your reply. The solution you proposed in the first section of your reply doesn't seem to work for me. The computer name does not change. I also tried using Start-Process directly from the powershell script and that did not work when the script was invoked via the gpedit.msc Shutdown properties setting. I initially tried using only powershell but it didn't work. I understand it's not advised to turn off UAC but it's only off while the script changes the name and then it's back on. So not a big deal.

@Dan: There is no need for Start-Process and, as noted, its use without -Wait may have been your problem.
If I directly specify your changeComputerName.ps1 script via the PowerShell Scripts tab in gpedit.msc,
it works as expected; perhaps you need to add -Force to Rename-Computer to avoid an interactive prompt,
though at least on my non-domain machine that doesn't seem to be necessary.

I just tried it with the -Force flag but still does not work. Even set the setting to run the Powershell scripts first and that has no effect.

@Dan, I have no explanation; it works for me. If you're interested in getting to the bottom of this (you may not be), append a redirection such as *>> c:\path\to\log\file.txt to your Rename-Computer call and examine the file after a reboot. As an aside: you can simplify the random-name generation expression to -join [char[]] (97..122 | Get-Random -Count 15)

Unfortunately, no output in the file. Tried on StartUp and Shutdown. So the script must not be running at all. Maybe the system is in a state where the powershell env is not able to run successfully.

That's unfortunate, @Dan. You can try to run commands interactively in the SYSTEM account if you have psexec installed, with psexec -s powershell ... (from an elevated session). Another thing you can try is to avoid script-file execution altogether, by putting the following into your runAs.bat file: powershell -c "Invoke-Expression (Get-Content -Raw C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\Machine\Scripts\Shutdown\changeComputerName.ps1)"

@Dan, is a domain-originated GPO in place that prevents script execution? GPO-based execution policies preempt -ExecutionPolicy CLI arguments, though I've found that running a shutdown script with -ExecutionPolicy Bypass somehow manages to override at least a local GPO that prevents script execution (or requires all scripts to be signed) - something that interactive calls, including via psexec -s, cannot do.

There is no domain policy as this box is not part of any. I did take a look in gpedit.msc and Filtered for Shutdown and found "Scripts (Startup/Shutdown)". It's set to Not Configured. But this seems to be related to snap-ins. However even if there was a setting, that would give carte blanche access to execute any scripts on Startup/Shutdown. That would have to be modified before my scripts would be able to be run. I will focus instead in seeing if I can make the .bat file command simpler based on your comments above. Thanks for all your suggestions so far.

Understood re domain, @Dan. I don't see Not Configured in gpedit.msc with respect to Scripts (Startup/Shutdown), but, to be clear: Placing scripts in C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\Machine\Scripts\Shutdown by itself is NOT enough. You must additionally explicitly designate such scripts - whether located in this special location or elsewhere - as to be run on startup / shutdown via the gpedit.msc GUI, as described in the question.

it's probably this one: Computer Configuration
-Administrative Templates   -Windows Components
-Windows PowerShell -> Turn on Script Execution or this one: User Configuration -Administrative Templates
-Windows Components     -Windows PowerShell -> Turn on Script Execution I found them here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27753917/how-do-you-successfully-change-execution-policy-and-enable-execution-of-powershe

I did designate scripts, however the above policies are not configured and they default to scripts not being allowed to run.

@Dan, these are the GPO policies that govern the effective PowerShell execution policy (reflected in the MachinePolicy and UserPolicy output lines when you run Get-ExecutionPolicy -List). If set to Undefined (reflected in gpedit.msc as Not Configured), they default to Restricted (meaning: script-file executions are disallowed), unless preempted by a higher-precedence scope (MachinePolicy has the highest precedence; Get-ExecutionPolicy -List lists in precedence order, highest first).

@Dan: However, as noted before, even though GPO-based policies normally prevent attempts at ad-hoc overrides via an -ExecutionPolicy Bypass argument in a CLI call, in the case of startup / shutdown scripts, specifically, such overrides do seem to work - at least in my tests on my non-domain-joined machine. For a comprehensive overview of PowerShell's execution policies - albeit without the special case at hand - see this answer.
